# Alternatives to testing private methods in TDD

Tags: tdd

I'm trying to use TDD when writing a class that needs to parse an XML document. Let's say the class is called XMLParser, and its constructor takes in a string for the path to the XML file to parse. I would like to have a Load() method that tries to load this XML into memory, and performs a few checks on the file such as file system errors, whether or not its an XML file, etc.

My question is about alternatives: I've read that it's bad practice to have private methods that you need to test, and that you should be able to just test the public interface and let the private methods do their thing. But in this case, this functionality is pretty important, and I don't think it should be public.

Does anyone have good advice for a scenario like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to redesign your architecture a bit. Currently, you have one high level class with low level functionality embedded. Split that into multiple classes that belong to different layers (I use the term "layer" very loosely here).

Example:

1. Have one class with the public interface of your current class. (-> High level layer)
2. Have one class responsible for loading files from disk and handling IO errors (-> Low level layer)
3. Have one class responsible for validating XML documents (-> Inbetween)

Now you can test all three of these classes independently!

You will see that your high level class will do not much more than just composing the two lower level classes.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Can you elaborate on #1 a bit? I like the idea of shuffling off #2 and #3 those tasks into testable yet separate classes.

Comment: @Monochromatic: I don't really understand the question in your comment. Those three points are not "either-or" options, you need to use them together. Having said that, what is not clear with the first step?

Answer (score 1):

Use no access modifier (which is the next up to private) and write the test in the same package.

Good OOD is important but for really important functionality testing is more important. Good practices are always only a guideline and they are good in the general scenario.

You could also try to encapsulate that specific file-checking behaviour in another object and have your parser instantiate it and use it. This is probably what I would do. In this way you could also even use this functionality somewhere else with minimal effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a subclass as part of your test package that exposes public accessors to the private methods (which should then be protected).

```
Public class TestableClass : MyClass
{
    public someReturnType TestMethod() {
        return base.PrivateMethod();
    }
}
```